# Бизнес логика в диалогах

Tags: c#, ui, ux, диалог

**Вопрос: размещаете ли Вы бизнес логику в диалоговых окнах или делаете их максимально простыми насколько возможно?**

Делаю SPA на Blazor. Требуется сделать изменение пароля авторизованного пользователя. Имеется текстовое поле с иконкой, при клике по которой открывается диалоговое окно, в котором нужно ввести текущий пароль и 2 раза новый. После успешной валидации отправляется запрос на сервер через сервис authStateProvider(полученный через DI). В ответ получаем или ошибку от сервера или успешное изменение пароля. На данный момент все работает, как описано выше, но меня мучают сомнения, что диалоги должны быть просто тупыми формами без каких-либо контейнеров, сервисов и прочего. Их задача - отредактировать данные/вернуть yes/no(при подтверждении чего-либо).

Если в диалоге убрать все "лишнее"(сервис, отправку запроса и.т.п) и только возвращать при save успешный результат в вызывающую форму, то придется в ней(в форме) реализовать бесконечную попытку сохранения пароля(если пользователь допускают ошибки, например, слабая сложность пароля). А т.к мы ожидаем ответ от сервера после закрытия диалога, то пользователь будет видеть постоянно открывающиеся/закрывающиеся диалоговые окна(пока обрабатывается запрос и снизу показывается какой-то статус) => ухудшение UX, но как мне кажется не идет нарушение SOLID. А в 1м случае наоборот нарушаем SOLID, но пользователь доволен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бизнес логику *нужно* делать на сервере.

Часть бизнес логики *можно* дублировать на presentation, если это улучшает опыт пользователя по работе с приложением.

Дублирование - да, это нарушение SRP (а не всего SOLID), но тут уже вам решать - вы для пользователя приложение делаете, или для соблюдения принципов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Валидация данных на клиенте, отправка запроса(на контроллер) в случае успешной валидации и показ пользователю какого-либо оповещения не является бизнес логикой? Речь идет именно о клиенте, а не о сервере

Comment: @Lapish валидация данных - это бизнес логика. отображение оповещения и  (не)отправка запроса на сервер - нет, это уже чисто presentation. Для случая пароля - валидацию дублируют на клиенте ради UX, показывают сообщение на клиенте ради UX. Но при этом та же самая валидация должна еще раз происходить на сервере, и сервер должен возвращать ошибку, если она не прошла. Потому что никогда нельзя верить тому, что произошло на клиенте. Например, магазины могут пересчитывать сумму в корзине на клиенте, но реальное суммирование всегда должен делать сервер. Иначе кто-то на клиенте может 0 вписать :)